# typescript async await operators promises and memoization pattern

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await, memoization

I'm trying to modernize some of my code with latest TypeScript enhancements.
We have a lot of memoization patterns in place. **The idea is that some services have multiple subscribers and we want to make sure everybody waits on one call and doesn't fire multiple calls**.
The code looks like that

```
private isAdmin: Promise<Boolean>;
public IsCurrentUserAdmin(): Promise<Boolean> {
if (!this.isAdmin) {
this.isAdmin = httpService.goGetTheData().then((data) => //do something and return Boolean);
}
return this.isAdmin;
```

**My question is: will something like that have the same effect as with the await operator I "don't have access to the promise object" ?**

```
public IsCurrentUserAdmin(): Promise<Boolean> {
const isAdminData = await httpService.goGetTheData();
// do something with the data to get the value
return isAdmin;
}
```

Comment: `return Boolean;` should be `return isAdmin;` in your second example, then they would be equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you absolutely need access to the promise object for the memoisation. `async`/`await` doesn't necessarily prevent that - it's just syntactic sugar for `then` calls - but in your particular case it doesn't really help. Since you're not caching the `goGetTheData()` promise, but the one returned by `.then(…)` (so that also the "do something" is executed just once), you would need to write an extra helper method for that:

```
private isAdmin: Promise<boolean>;
private async fetchIsAdmin(): Promise<boolean> {
    const data = await httpService.goGetTheData();
    // do something and
    return // a boolean
}
public IsCurrentUserAdmin(): Promise<boolean> {
    if (!this.isAdmin) {
        this.isAdmin = this.fetchIsAdmin();
    // you could `await this.isAdmin` in here as well, but that would happen for every call
    return this.isAdmin;
}
```

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks, I don't know TypeScript, I just copied the type the OP had